# void function bubble_sort doesn't sort arrays

Tags: c, sorting

A am trying an implementation of some sorting algorithms and I have to calculate how much time they spend. This is the function I wrote:

```
void bubble_sort(int A[], int len) {
bool ord = false;
    for (int i=0; i<len-1 && ord==false; i++) {
        ord = true;
        for (int j=len-1; j>i; j--) {
            if (A[j]-1>A[j]) {
                ord = false;
                swap(A[j]-1, A[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course here there is a typical `swap()` function:

```
void swap(int x, int y) {
    int d;
    d = x;
    x = y;
    y = d;
}
```

I am not having troubles with Insertion Sort, Selection Sort and Merge Sort. By the way `bubble_sort` is not sorting the numbers in my array.

I cannot find what's wrong. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: change to `void swap(int a[], int x, int y);`

Comment: In order to replace the entity.

Comment: there are several possible fixes, but as said by others, your swap is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `-1` in array `A`. Not outside the `[]`. Your code non just chech if value in `A[j]`minus 1 is bigger than value in `A[j]`. Which is obviously always `false`.

Also in swap function you dont pass the ponter of the Array `A`. Actually `swap()` does nothing.

Try

```
if (A[j-1]>A[j]) {
                ord = false;
              int temp=A[j-1];
           A[j-1]=A[j];
           A[j]=temp;
```

Comment: Your code works, going to accept it. I have also removed the swap function

Comment: @AlbertoRossi yes you remove swap and also declare `int temp` outside the loop for a cleaner code

Answer (score 3):

In C, function parameters are passed by value, not by reference.
your `swap()` function does nothing (it doesn't even return... didn't your compiler complain?)

To actually sort, you have to change `swap()` to

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) {
    int d = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = d;
    return;
}
```

and invoke it with

```
swap(&A[j-1], &A[j]);
```

Comment: I use wxDevC++ and it doesn't complain.

Comment: @EOF Your function is wrong. Read your the firs sentence of your own answer to fix it. Also your don't have to return a void function.